# Wrap and Marshal Go struct in required JSON parameter

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to create JSON to send to a Rails API that accepts the following format:

```
{"device":{"ipaddress":"192.168.1.2", "netmask": "255.255.255.0", "gateway": "192.168.1.1"}}
```

But I'm unsure of how to wrap what I've already marshaled into the `"device":{}` portion that the API accepts.

Here's what I have so far:

```
type Device struct {
    IPAddress string `json:"ipaddress"`
    Network   string `json:"network"`
    Gateway   string `json:"gateway"`
}

// gathers the IP info
func GatherIPInfo() {

    d := Device{
        IPAddress: "192.168.1.2",
        Network:   "255.255.255.0",
        Gateway:   "192.168.1.1",
    }

    // now send to API
    data, _ := json.Marshal(d) // looks like: {"ipaddress":"192.168.1.2","network":"255.255.255.0","gateway":"192.168.1.1"}

    ...
    ...
}
```

Do I have to create another struct to be able to achieve wrapping the existing into 'device' or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another struct to enclose the Device struct you have, or do something like this:

```
json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"device":d})
```

Comment: Perfect!  I love the succinct-ness of it!